# Package not found with apt-get install

Tags: linux, webrtc, rpm, apt-get, apprtcdemo

I am trying to install packages g++, libnss3-dev,libpulse-dev,libjpeg62-dev
libxv-dev,libgtk2.0-dev,libexpat1-dev in order to run AppRTCDemo. I am writing:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install g++
```

And I am getting the message that package can not be found. The same is for the other packages. I cant not find rpm-s ether. The Linux version is **Linux 3.18.1-pclos1 i686**.

Comment: I think you want to use `apt-get update` not `upgrade`. Not sure it will solve the problem, but worth a shot.

Comment: Yes, just a technical mistake, now is corrected (in the question, in terminal I did it with update, and i'm having the problem with installation)

Comment: The Linux kernel version doesn't know anything about user-level packages. Which Linux *distribution* are you running ?

Comment: pclinuxos from http://spout.ussg.indiana.edu/linux/pclinuxos/pclinuxos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

PCLinuxOS : Do not use `apt-get update`, but use the Refresh button in synaptic. PCLinuxOS is rpm based, and the "apt for rpm" behaves different than the Debian `apt`.

The PCLinuxOS package names are : { gcc-c++, libnss-devel, libjpeg62, libjpeg-devel, libxv-devel, libgtk+2.0_0-devel, libexpat1-devel }.

There is no "-devel" package for libjpeg62. 'libjpeg-devel' provides version 1.4.1 .

---

Comment: I'm using synaptic too, same results. I am configuring out that somehow this packages do not exist for this version (i'm new to Linux), but they were defined as prerequisites to run apprtcdemo for android. And the message is that they are not in PKG_CONFIG_PATH. And I think that the missing packages are the reason why I can not execute ninja -C out/Debug

Comment: ? Did you install the packages listed in my above post ?